# Awk - Compare every line to find a duplicate field, and add some wording to the end of line

Tags: text, awk, duplicates

I have a file like this file, and I am trying to verify one field of each line, and add some wording if that field has a duplicate earlier in the file.

```
\\FILE04\BUET-PCO;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CORP\ET\PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;/FS7_150a/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;10000bytes;9888;;;
\\FILE12\BUAG-GOLDMINE$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\AGENCY\GOLDMINE;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;90000bytes;98834;;;
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;;;
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;other stuff;;
```

In my example Line #3 and #4 have the same physical path.
I would to have a script that could compare third field for example /FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG against the same file, 
and if it found the exact match to print something like "same physical path as Line #" for both cases,

```
\\FILE04\BUET-PCO;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CORP\ET\PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;/FS7_150a/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;10000bytes;9888;;;
\\FILE12\BUAG-GOLDMINE$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\AGENCY\GOLDMINE;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;90000bytes;98834;;;
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;;;Same Physical Path as Line #4
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;other stuff;; Same Physical Path as Line #3
```

Comment: What should happen if a physical path occurs more than 2 times?  Would you want `Same Physical Path as Line #3, #4`?

Comment: @beny23 it should state if repeats at least with any other line, if possible with all the lines repeated, but if it's already marked it's enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. It is a little hackish, YMMV. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt{,}
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ";"
}

FNR==NR {
    array[$3]=array[$3] "#" NR
    next
}

{
    if ($3 in array && array[$3] ~ /#.#/) {
        copy = array[$3]
        sub("#"FNR, "", copy)
        printf "%s Same Physical Path as Line as %s\n", $0, copy
    }
    else {
        print
    }
}
```

Results:

```
\\FILE04\BUET-PCO;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CORP\ET\PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;/FS7_150a/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;10000bytes;9888;;;
\\FILE12\BUAG-GOLDMINE$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\AGENCY\GOLDMINE;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;90000bytes;98834;;;
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;;; Same Physical Path as Line as #4
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;other stuff;; Same Physical Path as Line as #3
```

Comment: I am on a gawk port version for Windows, I tried to use this code. But it seems to fail, I tried on cygwin also it runs but doesn't find any duplicate match

Comment: @Eduardo: I can confirm that this works in a linux environment. I'm using `GNU Awk 4.0.1`. I would highly recommend installing a linux distro, and removing windoze if you can live without it. What version of `GNU awk` on cygwin are you using? Perhaps try: `awk -f script.awk file.txt file.txt`

Comment: Thanks Steve, awk version on cygwin GNU Awk 4.0.1
I tried it in that way but seems to fail 
$ awk -f script.awk DFSvsShares.csv newfile.csv
awk: script.awk:7: fatal: cannot open file `newfile.csv' for reading (No such file or directory)
$ awk -f script.awk DFSvsShares.csv newfile.csv
awk: script.awk:7: fatal: cannot open file `newfile.csv' for reading (No such file or directory)

when I ran $ awk -f script.awk DFSvsShares.csv it completes but nothing appears on the stdout 
I will see if I can find a Linux host here

Comment: @Eduardo: You need to specify the filename of your file twice. `awk -f script.awk file.txt{,}` is actually shorthand for `awk -f script.awk file.txt file.txt`. In order for you to get the output you desire, the file must be read twice, so we must _tell_ `awk` to read the same file twice. You shouldn't be specifying two different filenames, nor should you be listing the filename only once.

Answer (score 2):

This code tackles a simplified version of your problem.  It identifies each line that contains a duplicate value compared to a previous line in field 3.  It doesn't handle the tagging of a line that has subsequent duplicates.

```
awk -F';' '{ tag = ""
             if (field3[$3] != 0) tag = " Same physical path as line " field3[$3]
             else field3[$3] = NR
             printf "%s%s\n", $0, tag
           }' "$@"
```

There are probably other ways to organize it, but the key point is to use the associative array `field3` to keep track of which names are seen in field 3 and the line number at which a given name was first seen.  This assumes you're processing a single file of input.  Lookup FNR etc if you must process multiple files (but you have to decide whether the same name can appear in different files or not).

It works almost as desired on the data given:

```
\\FILE04\BUET-PCO;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CORP\ET\PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;/FS7_150a/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;10000bytes;9888;;;
\\FILE12\BUAG-GOLDMINE$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\AGENCY\GOLDMINE;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;90000bytes;98834;;;
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;;;
\\FILE12\BUGB-BUSINTEG$;\\SERVER24\DFS\SHARED\CAN\GB\BUSINTEG;/FS3_150a/FILE12/BU/GB/BUSINTEG;50000bytes;988822;other stuff;; Same physical path as line 3
```

The difficulty with producing the 'tag' on line 3 is predicting the future; it is hard.  To do that, you'd have to slurp the entire file into memory, keeping tabs on the line numbers where a given value in field 3 appears (in general, that could be an extensive list of line numbers), and then iterating through the data and tagging appropriately.  Very, very much harder to do; I'd prefer to use Perl to `awk` for that job, though it is probably feasible to organize the data correctly in `awk` too.

Were it me, I'd be OK with the 90% of the job done; lines with duplicates are identified.  If you want the last 10% done, expect it to take the other 90% of the time planned for the first phase.