# awk sed - compare text withing a file, search for a string, look for repeated instances on the same file, add some wording at EOL

Tags: string, text, sed, awk, compare

I have a big text file which contains similar entries like this

My goal here is to identify if a a parent folder exists, and by that I mean if a for example /FS7_100x/FILE04 would be a parent folder for this folder : /FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE

the relationship between those two paths is that they share the same path at some point.
Why do I want to do this? because by doing this I know if the space used by that path is already counted in a parent folder.

3rd field is populated with a filesystem path, I want to compare each path on each line against the same file, same 3rd field, adding a slash / in the end of the path. 
This means: compare: /FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE  vs /FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE & /FS3_200g/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE & /FS3_200g/FILE12

For example, 
I want to find /FS7_100x/FILE04/ and /FS3_200g/FILE12/

file1

```
\\FILE04\BUET-PCO;\\SERVER24\OFFICE;/FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL;
\\FILE12\BUAG-GOLDMINE$;\\SERVER24\GOLDMINE;/FS3_200g/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;
\\x\a$;\\SERVER24\DFS\somethingelse;/FS3_200g/FILE12;
\\z\o;\\SERVER24\DFS\blah;/FS7_100x/FILE04;
```

Fields are separated with "; "

In this way I can determine that a parent folder is already listed on file1, 
and I want to add some words to the end of line (the line which is already contained on another one) for example saying: Physical path is a subfolder of Line#

desired output:

```
\\FILE04\BUET-PCO;\\SERVER24\OFFICE;/FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL;Physical path is a subfolder of Line#4
\\FILE12\BUAG-GOLDMINE$;\\SERVER24\GOLDMINE;/FS3_200g/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;Physical path is a subfolder of Line#3
\\x\a$;\\SERVER24\DFS\somethingelse;/FS3_200g/FILE12;
\\z\o;\\SERVER24\DFS\blah;/FS7_100x/FILE04;
```

What I did:

```
setlocal enableextensions 
del lugares.csv
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=;" %%i in (file1.csv) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ('findstr /N /i /r /C:"%%k/" file1.csv') do (
echo Original %%k;%%i;%%j; --- repeated with Line# %%p >>dupli.txt
)
)
pause
```

I do not want to create a new file called dupli.txt I want all the data been poured onto the original file: file1.csv, so my solution does not work for me.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  Do you want to compare *every* instance of the 3rd field with some other part of the line?  What is the relationship between lines 1 and 3, and lines 2 and 4?  What identifies lines 3 and 4 as sources for comparison as opposed to lines 1 and 2?  This isn't nearly clear enough to answer, I think.  Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12709865/edit) and make it more clear?

Comment: @ghoti I updated the question, yes I want to compare every instance of the 3rd field, against the same 3rd field but from the rest of the lines. The relationship between lines 1 and 3: no match, nothing expected to be done here, lines 2 and 4: no match, nothing to be done here, Why lines 3 and 4 would bring some useful information? it's because they are parent folders for the other folders.

Comment: What about multiple matches?  Say, `/FS3_100g/foo` is a parent of `/FS3_100g/foo/bar`, how do you decide which should be the parent of `/FS3-100g/foo/bar/grelb` ?

Comment: @ghoti for that case if it's possible to for example state, that `/FS3-100g/foo/bar/grelb` has two parent folder e.g. `/FS3-100g/foo/bar/grelb; Physical path is a subfolder of Line#1 #2`, assuming Line#1=`/FS3_100g/foo` & Line#2=`/FS3_100g/foo/bar`. That would be the thing that I would like most

Comment: Related to [SO 12631430](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631430/awk-compare-every-line-to-find-a-duplicate-field-and-add-some-wording-to-the) based on author and sample data file, even if some of the details may be different this time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could use `sed` for this, I think this is the sort of thing that `awk` was built for.

If your text file is very long, then I think doing this in two passes makes the most sense, so that you don't have to load the entire thing into memory.

First you get a list of potential parents:

```
awk -F\; '{print $3}' file1 > paths.txt
```

Now you read that into an array and compare it against other lines in the file.  I called the file **`pathrefs.awk`**.  The command line would be:

```
awk -f pathrefs.awk paths.txt file1
```

The contents of `pathrefs.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
        FS=";"
}

# First, process the paths.txt file...
NR==FNR {
        paths[$0"/"]=NR;
        next;
}

# Next, process the second file, using data gathered from the first file.
{
        delete ref;

        # Make a reference list of paths that match the current line's $3
        for (i in paths) {
                if (index($3,i)==1) {
                        ref[paths[i]];
                }
        }

        # If we found anything...
        if (length(ref)) {
                 $0=$0 "Parent:";
        }

        # Show the list.
        for (i in ref) {
                $0=$0 " #" i;
        }
}

# This is short-hand for "print;"
1
```

Here's sample input data I used:

```
this;abcde;/FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;;;;;;;;;;
that;bcdef;/FS3_200g/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;;;;;;;;;;;
foo;cdefg;/FS3_200g/FILE12;;;;;;;;
bar;defgh;/FS7_100x/FILE04;;;;;;;;;;;
baz;efghi;/FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D;;;;;;;;;;;
```

And here's the output the script generated:

```
this;abcde;/FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D/PROJECT CONTROL OFFICE;;;;;;;;;;Parent: #4 #5
that;bcdef;/FS3_200g/FILE12/BU/AGENCY/GOLDMINE;;;;;;;;;;;Parent: #3
foo;cdefg;/FS3_200g/FILE12;;;;;;;;
bar;defgh;/FS7_100x/FILE04;;;;;;;;;;;
baz;efghi;/FS7_100x/FILE04/BU-D;;;;;;;;;;;Parent: #4
```

Note that I've changed the wording from what you specified in your question so that the results display better on StackOverflow.  Use whatever you like in place of `"Parent:"`.

If you think you can handle the memory requirements to load your entire file into memory, then you may be able to write the entire process into a single script.  What I've written so far describes the logic you'll employ.

Comment: Thank you your script couldn't be better